# Shrink bottom element at bottom of Gmail inbox page

Tags: gmail

Gmail is adding such a large border to the elements at the bottom of my screen (boxed in red below) that it has to add a scrollbar. Is there anyway to reduce the border size?

[image: gmail]

Comment: Are you sure it's not because the side bar on the left is so long? Try closing the chat window.

Comment: The folders and chat both have a separate scroll bars. But closing chat does not fix the problem. Looking at the HTML of the red box the bottom margin of the highlighted region is 180 pixels. So it's actually specified to be rather large